# How to change the color of UITabbarViewController's navigationBar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uicolor

There is a UITabBarController

```
- (void)getToMCGatherViewController
{
    mCGatherViewController = [[MCGatherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MCGatherViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mCGatherViewController];
    navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
    [navigationController release];
}
```

In the .h file:

```
 @interface MCGatherViewController : UITabBarController
```

In the .m file . I want to change the color of the view's navigationBar

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor greenColor];
}
```

and it does not work at all.

Help me with this problem , thank you in advance!

Comment: Your question is complicated please clarify what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add

```
[navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

after

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mCGatherViewController];
```

in your getToMCGatherViewController method.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your code like this and try I think this will work for you.

```
mCGatherViewController = [[MCGatherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MCGatherViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mCGatherViewController];
navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self.view addSubview:nav.view];
```

Then you change your Navigation Bar tint color.